# Does Riemann integrability on closed interval implies uniform boundedness?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

Does Riemann integrability on closed interval implies uniform boundedness?

My thought process points to yes, because if f is Riemann integrable then it is bounded pointwise on [a,b]. I could be wrong, but I very vaguely remember from more elementary analysis that this implies uniform boundedness on that interval.

Comment: Thanks, I was leaning towards that but was a little shaky.

Comment: What do you mean by "uniform boundedness" of a single function? Just that it is bounded on $[a,b]$? The answer then is "yes".

Comment: ^Yeah that was what I meant.

Comment: @Isaac: that can be posted as an answer.

Comment: **What do you mean by "pointwise bounded" and "uniformly bounded" for a single function?** That is very confusing terminology.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of Riemann integral involves taking arbitrary sample points in subintervals, or supremum or infimum over said subintervals. Either process fails to arrive at a finite value if the function is unbounded. Thus, a Riemann integrable function must be bounded.

That said, the *improper* Riemann integral is defined in greater generality, and it can be finite for some unbounded functions such as $x^{-1/2}$ on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

A continuous, pointwise bounded function is uniformly bounded on any compact set $X$, as can be seen by considering the cover $X_n=\{x \in X:|f(x)|<n\}$.

Comment: This only works if we assume $f$ is continuous, which need not be the case.